# Correct image path to use in template files of custom themes

Tags: 7, theming

I'm creating a custom theme. Under my theme's folder, there is an `images` folder where I've put some pictures. I want to use these images in my various template (`.tpl.php`) files using HTML `<img>` tag... but the problem is how do i get correct path for these images (the `src` attribute)?

I've searched for a while but didn't get any solutions. Please help.

**EDIT:** I'm using nice urls (http://mydrupalsite.com/a/b/c/d) - type URLs. So, if the image `src` begins with `/` (or any relative path) it would break.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think these functions could be useful in your templates:

```
print base_path() . path_to_theme();
```

[path_to_theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7) Return the path to the current themed element.
[base_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/base_path/7) The base path of the Drupal installation.

for example, I have an image called `bg-bar.png` inside `images` directory in my template directory called `garland`. then I can use `base_path()` and `path_to_theme()` to get the path to the image, for example inside node.tpl.php:

```
print '<img src="'.base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/images/bg-bar.png">';
```

**Update:** if you want to use the current domain, you can use `global $base_root`:

```
  $address = ''.base_path() . path_to_theme() .'/images/bg-bar.png';
  global $base_root;
  echo '<img src="' . $base_root . $address . '">';
```

I hope information be useful.

Comment: I've tried all these. Problem is, `base_path()` returns '/' - which does not help when I'm using nice urls (i.e. http://mysite.com/a/b/c) - in this case image source becomes '/path-to-theme/...../image.png' - which does not work. I need to use `http://` instead of `/` in image source I guess.

Comment: I updated my answer with information related with `http://`.

Comment: If you are using 'nice urls' I guess that these urls are controlled by a rewrite process, so I think that you can add exeptions. For example, review if from `.htaccess` file you can control this rewrite process, and add the respective condition with `RewriteCond` to exclude images.

Comment: Thank you! I have been looking all over for a solution for this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since my image was in a conditional block, the above syntax posed some problems and the following worked for me.   However, I am not sure if it is advisable from a maintenance perspective:

```
src='<?php print base_path().path_to_theme().'/images/iphone.png' ?>'
```